# Can we use vb.net in MVC Asp.net 2017

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

Can we use vb.net lagnuage in MVC ASP.NET 2017 or latest version of Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Yes, of course you can create MVC project with VB.NET. What you want to do next? Please explain in detail.

Comment: Thanx for your reply , want to create e commerce website in asp.net MVC , but when we go to create new website with MVC it is not showing vb .

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I see no reason why that wouldn't be possible.

In Visual Studio 2017 you have the options to create an ASP.NET MVC 5 / Web API project using Visual Basic as usual.

I'm unsure whether you'll be able to create ASP.NET Core / MVC 6 applications using VB.NET, since I havn't been able to find any sources confirming this. I reckon, though, that it should be possible, since VB.NET works perfectly fine with .NET Core.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply , actually i am newer in VS 2017 that is why i am asking about that